# Попытка создать цикл for для рисования SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Я только начал изучать SVG и хотел создать цикл for для рисования множества кругов в моем HTML. Можно ли это сделать так, как я пытаюсь сделать, или то, что я пытаюсь сделать, невозможно?

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG for loop</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var circlex = 50; 
    var circley = 50;

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    <svg width="100" height="100">
         <circle cx="circlex + 1" cy="circley + 1" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
    };

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Trying to make a for loop to draw an SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34201318/7394871) от участника  [@user2703522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703522/user2703522).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/34201318/7394871

Answer (score 4):

### Видит око да зуб неймет

Вы не можете поместить html-код прямо в JavaScript (это было бы круто)
JavaScript добавляет новые элементы через манипуляции с DOM.
Итак, давайте рассмотрим код:

1. Сначала создайте пустой документ SVG с xmlns (просто установите `xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, он работает в 99% случаях), и нам нужен идентификатор для выбора элемента.
2. Получите элемент SVG в JavaScript: `document.getElementById ("svg_circles")`. Здесь мы используем идентификатор, который мы установили для элемента, чтобы сохранить его в переменной.
3. В цикле for: создайте круговой элемент: `var circle = document.createElementNS (NS, "circle");` Пространство имен NS находится в 1. Это http://www.w3.org/2000/svg. Это кажется сложным, но это необходимо и просто то, что вам нужно запомнить.
4. Установите атрибуты круга:  я установил положение `cx` и `cy` с помощью .`setAttribute()`. Вы можете попробовать расположить их по-другому. Я также установил атрибут размера `r` и заливку (длинная строка кода на заливке с моей стороны просто для развлечения, она создает случайные цвета)
5. Теперь мы закончили с кругами, но код JavaScript не знает, куда их поместить. Итак, мы говорим: `svgCircle.appendChild()` устанавливает элемент как дочерний для нашего документа SVG.
   Итак: `svgCircle.appendChild(circle);` где круг - это созданный элемент SVG.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var circlex = 0;
  var circley = 0;

  var svgCircle = document.getElementById("svg_circles");
  var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var circle = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
    console.log(circle);
    circle.setAttribute("cx", circlex + i);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", circley + i);
    circle.setAttribute("r", 10);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ")");
    svgCircle.appendChild(circle);
  };
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg_circles" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202622/7394871) от участника  [@Persijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3999748/persijn).</sub>

Comment: Мне интересно производительность такого метода, будет ли разница в том, если сгенерировать в агрегатор и один раз записать в svg все круги или каждый раз добавлять круг

Comment: @Greg--  затрудняюсь ответить, надо сравнивать, пробовать.